# How to make project from github

Tags: c++, git

I am downloading a library from the github

/////////////////////

https://github.com/ossrs/srs

///////////////////////////

The steps which i follow are

1. Create a folder
2. Run power shell and point to the folder
3. Git clone the source

The issue i am facing is the Make command in the step 2 of installation

The power shell does not accept the make command , so how do i make the source.

Comment: @T3H40 thanks yes it does answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make is an UNIX command for the UNIX make utility. To compile it on Windows, you can use Visual Studio, by running the Developer Command Prompt for VS, and using Microsoft's version of this tool - nmake: `nmake -f Makefile`

However, it looks like the configure script in /src of the package can only run on UNIX, so if you want to build this package yourself, it will be easier to use the Windows Subsystem for Linux, which will let you run a Linux environment that supports the commands in the configure file as well as the Make set up.

Comment: can you please recommend any subsystem that i can use

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu 18.04 should be the easiest to use and is the least likely to cause compatibility and dependency issues. [Ubuntu 18.04 on the Windows Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu-1804-lts/9n9tngvndl3q?activetab=pivot:overviewtab)

Comment: @shomit alternatively, you can run this package using a pre-compiled image on Docker, which is available for Windows. https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/, https://hub.docker.com/r/ossrs/srs

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1:**
You can try git clone using the https address of your repository

```
git clone https://github.com/ossrs/srs.git
```

This will add a folder to the directory where you did `git clone`
[image: git clone]

**Method 2:**

- Download Zip from git repository as shown in the image above
- Unzip the files and add it to your project.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply click on the green `Code` button, then `Download ZIP` instead of using powershell and git.